# Safari returning wrong CSS value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I'm trying to replace a `<select>` element with a `<div>` that perfectly matches it using jQuery. Unfortunately browsers all argue on the actual width/height of the object, so I have it so you need to manually enter a height. However, I want it so that the height you enter includes the padding height, so when setting the height of the div - I used this code

```
$(divObject).height(options.height - $(this)
  .css("padding-top")
    .replace("px", "") - $(this)
      .css("padding-bottom")
        .replace("px", ""))
```

Where `$(this)` is the `<select>` element.

This works fine in all browsers... Except Safari. Safari has somehow decided that even if I explicitly set padding-top and padding-bottom to, say, 5px - that the actual values are 2px.

Being cross-browser compliant on this is really taking me to my wit's end here. Any help would be much appreciated :(

Comment: When you examine the element in the developer console, does it also show as having the wrong padding size?

Comment: Also you may want to read over your question; parts of it don't make any sense ("I'm trying to element with a that perfectly matches it" ... huh?)

Comment: Yes - they are being shown in the Safari console with having padding 2px. But my test page is very simple, there's nothing I've said that could make it think I meant 2px. And yeah sorry, I had HTML elements in there - I didn't realise they were being omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use [jQuery.outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)?

Comment: Well you can *get* the height that way, but (I think) he's trying to *set* the height - and you can't do that with ".outerHeight()".  He'd have to set it to some trial value, get the outer height, and then adjust to the desired height appropriately.

Comment: @Pointy: If you set element width with respect of [jQuers.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) you can use `jQuery.outerHeight` to verify the **real** outer height and if needed to correct the element height.

Comment: actually this is one of the things I meant about browsers sucking with this. Different browsers return different heights to me

Comment: @Stephen Cook: Do you tried the `jQuery.outerHeight` function in your case? If you goes through gebugger you will see that the browser independend code of `jQuery.outerHeight` is not so easy, but in my tests it works good. If you found a problem it would be good if you post code which can be used to reproduce the problem. (including HTML code fragment of course). The best would be the code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MinatureCookie/CLTZh/1/ - I think that the problem is as Pointy noted, that Safari actually sets my padding to 2px despite it being set to 5px...